# Collision with irregular shapes

Tags: java, javafx, collision, intersection, detection

I'm working on a java project in which I'll be using diamond shapes. I've been thinking about a way to detect collision between two irregular shapes, but I just can't seem to find one that doesn't require a big amount of lines or a framework. Does anyone know a good way to detect collision between two irregular shapes?

Thanks.

PS: This is the way I wanted to do it at first but obviously this won't work.[image]

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sedj601/CollisionDectionFx) may help.

Comment: If you can create a test of whether a single point falls within the boundary of your diamond, you can just perform that same check against the four corners of the collision candidate.